# How to return and update a table in bookshelf knex

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am using postgresql, knex, and bookshelf to make queries to update my users table. I would like to find all users who didn't sign in during a specific time and then update their numAbsences and numTardies field.

However it appears that when running a raw sql query using bookshelf.knex the result that I get for users is an array of objects rather than an array of bookshelf objects of objects because I can't save the objects directly to the database when I try to use .save(). I get the exception `user.save is not a function`.

Does anyone know how I can update the values in the database for the users? I've seen the update function but I need to also return the users in absentUsers so I select them currently.

```
// field indicates whether the student was late or absent
var absentUsers = function(field){
  // returns all users who did not sign in during a specific time
  if (ongoingClasses){
    return bookshelf.knex('users')
      .join('signed_in', 'signed_in.studentId', '=', 'users.id')
      .where('signed_in.signedIn', false)
      .select()
      .then(function(users){
        markAbsent(users, field);
        return users;
      });
  }
}

var markAbsent = function(users, field){
  users.forEach(function(user){
    user[field]++;
    user.save();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by using another sql query in knex. It seemed there was no way to use a sql query and then use standard bookshelf knex methods since the objects returned were not bookshelf wrapper objects.

```
var absentUsers = function(field){
  // returns all users who did not sign in during a specific time
  if (ongoingClasses){
    return bookshelf.knex('users')
      .join('signed_in', 'signed_in.studentId', '=', 'users.id')
      .where('signed_in.signedIn', false)
      .select()
      .then(function(users){
        markAbsent(users, field);
      });
  }
}

var markAbsent = function(users, field){
  users.forEach(function(user){
    var updatedUser = {};
    updatedUser[field] = user[field]+1;
    bookshelf.knex('users')
      .where('users.id', user.id)
      .update(updatedUser).then(function(){
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code `bookshelf.knex('users')` you leave the "Bookshelf world" and are in "raw knex world". Knex alone doesn't know about your Bookshelf wrapper objects.

You may use [Bookshelf query](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-query) method to get the best of both worlds.

Assuming your model class is `User`, your example would look approximately like

```
User.query(function(qb) {
        qb.join('signed_in', 'signed_in.studentId', 'users.id')
          .where('signed_in.signedIn', false);
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .then(function(bookshelfUserObjects) {
      /*mark absent*/
      return bookshelfUserObjects.invokeThen('save');    // <1>
    });
```

<1> [invokeThen](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-invokeThen): Call model method on each instance in collection